# Outputting something i dont want to

Tags: python, output

I am really new. I've been learning python for like 5-6 days and I am doing some easy little projects. Well, I got a project where there's a randomly generated number. I input a number and it tells me if I guessed the randomly generated number. The code is bad but I don't know much more so that's what I managed to do.

Here is my code:

```
# The idea is that when you enter a number 0-20 it shows you if you guessed the number or no.
import random
computer_number = str(random.randint(0, 20))
person_number = str(input("Please insert a random number 0-20: "))

##############

if person_number != computer_number:
    if person_number > computer_number:
        if person_number > str(20):
            print()
            print("You entered a number that's higher than the possible.")
        print()
        print("Your number is too high! The computer chose " + computer_number)
    elif person_number < computer_number:
        if person_number < str(0):
            print()
            print("You entered a number that's lower than the possible.")
        print()
        print("Your number is too low! The computer chose " + computer_number)
    else:
        print()
        print("You entered an invalid option.")

##############

elif person_number == computer_number:
    print()
    print("You guessed the number! Congratulations")

input("""
Press ENTER to close the program.""")
```

I'm also tired so I might just not see the problem but, whatever number I input, it always shows these 2 strings:

```
You entered a number that's higher than the possible.
Your number is too high! The computer chose " + computer_number
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are comparing strings. You should be comparing ints. This will make the comparisons behave as you would expect.

Comment: Just a quick note, but probably not a full solution, the first two lines you've made your number and the computer number to be strings?

Comment: Why are you converting numbers to strings?. Let the number be numbers while comparasing them. Only convert them when you want to print them.

Comment: Are you saying that the program literally prints '+ computer_number' or are you saying that you don't want both lines of output, just one?

Comment: As others said, you should not convert numbers to strings, because inequality operators on strings use the lexicographical order. This means, for example, that '3' > '20' is unexpectedly equals to True. For more, check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Answer (score -1):

Try this it should work:

```
import random
computer_number = (random.randint(0, 20))
person_number = int(input("Please insert a random number 0-20: "))

##############

if person_number != computer_number:
    if person_number > computer_number:
        if person_number > (20):
            print()
            print("You entered a number that's higher than the possible.")
        print()
        print("Your number is too high! The computer chose " + str(computer_number))
    elif person_number < computer_number:
        if person_number < (0):
            print()
            print("You entered a number that's lower than the possible.")
        print()
        print("Your number is too low! The computer chose " + str(computer_number))
    else:
        print()
        print("You entered an invalid option.")

##############

elif person_number == computer_number:
    print()
    print("You guessed the number! Congratulations")

input("""Press ENTER to close the program.""")
```

Just changed the code to make the comparisons between numbers in "int".